# O que é o apvector do C++

Tags: c++, classificação

O professor da faculdade, pediu pra pesquisar sobre os scripts de ordenação e realizar testes com eles, determinando qual é melhor em que situação.

Encontrei os scripts, porém [no site o cara não mostra como executar](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Arrays/Bubble.htm), e ele utiliza um `apvector` que não sei de onde vem, por isso não consigo executar os scripts.

**Esse `apvector` é alguma biblioteca? Com consigo executar esse script?**

```
// Bubble Sort Function for Descending Order 
void BubbleSort(apvector <int> &num)
{
      int i, j, flag = 1;    // set flag to 1 to start first pass
      int temp;             // holding variable
      int numLength = num.length( ); 
      for(i = 1; (i <= numLength) && flag; i++)
     {
          flag = 0;
          for (j=0; j < (numLength -1); j++)
         {
               if (num[j+1] > num[j])      // ascending order simply changes to <
              { 
                    temp = num[j];             // swap elements
                    num[j] = num[j+1];
                    num[j+1] = temp;
                    flag = 1;               // indicates that a swap occurred.
               }
          }
     }
     return;   //arrays are passed to functions by address; nothing is returned
}
```

Comment: - Fonte do [`apvector.cpp`](ftp://ftp.cs.berkeley.edu/ucb/people/clancy/fish.code/AP.CS.classes/apvector.cpp);
- Sobre a classe [`apvector`](https://academics.tjhsst.edu/compsci/CS2C/U2/array.html)

Comment: Opa, consegue colocar a resposta dando exemplo de como eu importo essa classe no meu arquivo `ordenacoes.cpp`, estou utilizando Dev C++. Assim já posso considerar como resposta válida. Valeu! :D

Comment: Consigo sim, mas dá uma olhada antes e se realmente te ajuda, não manjo de C e foi mais uma pesquisa pra ajudar.

Comment: Abre um novo projeto como biblioteca dinâmica e compila o `apvector.cpp`, depois importe a dll para seu projeto. se o devc++ usa makefile, basta acrescentar o arquivo `apvector.cpp` na compilação, se quiser tentar compilar pelo gcc, basta usar `g++ apvector.cpp meuprojeto.cpp -o projeto.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classe *Apvector* é baseada na classe *Vector*, e todos os métodos pertencentes a ela também fazem parte da Vector. É um template que você poderá especificar com qual tipo de coleção ela trabalhará.

Algumas características da Apvector:

1. São como *arrays* e seu índice inicia-se a partir do zero
2. Podem ser inicializados para manter o mesmo valor em cada índice, provendo um segundo argumento para o construtor enquanto o vector é definido.
3. Podem ser redimensionados
4. Devem ser passados por referência

A seguir segue o modelo de implementação da classe [Apvector](https://academics.tjhsst.edu/compsci/CS2C/U2/array.html)

```
// *******************************************************************
//  APCS vector class  IMPLEMENTATION
//
//  see vector.h for complete documentation of functions
//
//  vector class consistent with a subset of the standard C++ vector class
//  as defined in the draft ANSI standard (part of standard template library)
// *******************************************************************


#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include "apvector.h"

template <class itemType>
apvector<itemType>::apvector()
//postcondition: vector has a capacity of 0 items, and therefore it will
//               need to be resized
    : mySize(0),
      myList(0)      
{

}

template <class itemType>
apvector<itemType>::apvector(int size)
// precondition: size >= 0
// postcondition: vector has a capacity of size items
   : mySize(size),
     myList(new itemType[size])
{

}

template <class itemType>
apvector<itemType>::apvector(int size, const itemType & fillValue)
// precondition: size >= 0
// postcondition: vector has a capacity of size items, all of which are set
//                by assignment to fillValue after default construction
    : mySize(size),
      myList(new itemType[size])
{
    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        myList[k] = fillValue;
    }
}

template <class itemType>
apvector<itemType>::apvector(const apvector<itemType> & vec)
// postcondition: vector is a copy of vec
    : mySize(vec.length()),
      myList(new itemType[mySize])
{
    int k;
        // copy elements
    for(k = 0; k < mySize; k++){
        myList[k] = vec.myList[k];
    }
}

template <class itemType>
apvector<itemType>::~apvector ()
// postcondition: vector is destroyed     
{
    delete [] myList;
}

template <class itemType>
const apvector<itemType> &
apvector<itemType>::operator = (const apvector<itemType> & rhs)
// postcondition: normal assignment via copying has been performed;
//                if vector and rhs were different sizes, vector
//                has been resized to  match the size of rhs
{
    if (this != &rhs)                           // don't assign to self!
    {
        delete [] myList;                       // get rid of old storage
        mySize = rhs.length();
        myList = new itemType [mySize];         // allocate new storage

            // copy rhs
        int k;
        for(k=0; k < mySize; k++)
        {
            myList[k] = rhs.myList[k];
        }
    }
    return *this;                               // permit a = b = c = d
}

template <class itemType>
int apvector<itemType>::length() const
// postcondition: returns vector's size (number of memory cells 
//                allocated for vector)
{
    return mySize; 
}

template <class itemType>
itemType & apvector<itemType>::operator [] (int k)
// description: range-checked indexing, returning kth item
// precondition: 0 <= k < length()
// postcondition: returns the kth item     
{

    if (k < 0 || mySize <= k)
    {
        cerr << "Illegal vector index: " << k << " max index = ";
        cerr << (mySize-1) << endl;
        abort();
    }
    return myList[k]; 
}

template <class itemType>
const itemType & apvector<itemType>::operator [] (int k) const
// safe indexing, returning const reference to avoid modification
// precondition: 0 <= index < length
// postcondition: return index-th item
// exception: aborts if index is out-of-bounds
{
    if (k < 0 || mySize <= k)
    {
        cerr << "Illegal vector index: " << k << " max index = ";
        cerr << (mySize-1) << endl;
        abort();
    }
    return myList[k]; 
}

template <class itemType>
void apvector<itemType>::resize(int newSize)
// description:  resizes the vector to newSize elements
// precondition: the current capacity of vector is length(); newSize >= 0
// postcondition: the current capacity of vector is newSize; for each k
//                such that 0 <= k <= min(length, newSize), vector[k]
//                is a copy of the original; other elements of vector are 
//                initialized using the 0-argument itemType constructor
//                Note: if newSize < length, elements may be lost
{
    int k;        
    int numToCopy = newSize < mySize ? newSize : mySize;

         // allocate new storage and copy element into new storage

    itemType * newList = new itemType[newSize];
    for(k=0; k < numToCopy; k++)
    {
        newList[k] = myList[k];
    }
    delete [] myList;                      // de-allocate old storage
    mySize = newSize;                      // assign new storage/size
    myList = newList;
}
```

@edit

> @Maniero - Qual a vantagem dela em relação à Vector?

- A classe verifica as subrotinas em tempo de execução para garantir
  que sempre fiquem dentro do limite, evitando assim bugs de `out of
  bounds`.
- O tamanho do apvector é armazenado em um `Vector`, eliminando assim a
  necessidade de uma variável extra.
- Um apvector pode ser copiado para outro utilizando o operador de
  atribuição.
- Quando o apvetor é declarado, o compilador aloca apenas um espaço na
  pilha com o seu tamanho e um ponteiro para a matriz real, porque a
  matriz real é alocada dinamicamente na memória livre.

---

- [Fonte¹](https://academics.tjhsst.edu/compsci/CS2C/U2/array.html)
- [Fonte²](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~rkrane/clecs/vcguide/c6.html)
- [Apvector.h](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/code/apvector.h)
- [Apvector.cpp](ftp://ftp.cs.berkeley.edu/ucb/people/clancy/fish.code/AP.CS.classes/apvector.cpp)

Comment: Boa resposta, só fiquei com uma dúvida, qual a vantagem dela em relação à `Vector`?

Comment: @bigown adicionei a resposta para tua questão.

Comment: Acho que esta é a definição do `Vector`. Está me parecendo uma classe sem utilidade prática alguma.